# How to convert date from one format to another golang

Tags: date, go

I am converting a date into unix timestamp and fetching the date using split as follows

```
tm := time.Unix(1470009600, 0).UTC()
dateString := strings.Split(tm.String(), " ")
```

The output of dateString is `2016-07-15` i.e. YYYY-MM-DD format. How can I convert this into DD-MMM-YY format? eg: 15-Jul-16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Format`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) method with the appropriate format:

```
fmt.Println(tm.Format("02-Jan-06")) // Prints "01-Aug-16".
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/uYDYzPwnbJ.